# Admin-only content for a cached page

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, caching

I have an Asp.Net MVC 5 website. In this website, I've got a page which is pretty complex and lots of queries are made to build it. The problem is, I want to add some controls on this page (or hide some elements) for admin users. My first thought was add a JavaScript file which creates admin-only content and add it via a `<script>` tag in a donut cache method. However, although the donut cache method is called every time, it adds the content if the first user visiting that page is an admin (hence, all the users seeing afterwards will see the controls and for the admin users, the JavaScript will render twice!

I could make a donut cache method for each element but it breaks the point of even creating a cache. What's the point of caching a page if you're going to create all the elements each time someone visits that page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could possibly use the OutputCache's `VaryByCustom` property in order to differentiate Admin from regular users.

In the `GetVaryByCustomString` global.asax override you could inspect the `HttpContext`, the current `Principal`, etc., in order to determine that.

[Source](http://visitmix.com/writings/using-varybycustom-with-outputcache-in-asp-net-mvc-to-support-caching-for-logged-in-users).

That way you'd have one cache for regular users and a different one for Admins.

Comment: Thank you very very very much. I'm so happy I'm freaking out right now!!

BTW, I used this code instead of author's solution:
`//inside GetVaryByCustomString
if (arg == "IsAdmin") { return context.User.IsInRole("admin") ? "admin" : "other"; }

return base.GetVaryByCustomString(context, arg);`

Comment: Excellent! Glad to help and thanks for providing additional info on your solution, it could be useful to somebody else as well.